# call popover and send back variable to previous uiview

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have an UITableViewController created with storyboard. 
Than I have an anchor that call a popOver created with storyboard as well. The popover is another UItableViewController, when I click on a row I should call back the first controller and pass an object.
I have tried this in the popover object:

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Fortune"]){

  ```
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;

  ASFortuneTeller * aController = [segue destinationViewController];
  [aController setWYPT:[allWYPTs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  ```

  }
  }

Basically I need to pass a NSMutableDictionary bag to the first UITableViewController.
But I have noticed that in this way I create a new ASFortuneTeller object , that is not what I want... I want just to call back the first controller and pass an object.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution (when it involves always the same two classes) could be:

In the .h file of the first view controller, define a method (or just a property):

```
-(void)selectedWYPT:(NSMutableDictionary*)wypt;
```

Within the .h file of your second view controller make a property

```
@property FirstUIViewController *firstView;
```

In the first view controller, you will open the second view controller via a segue, so there you can use:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifier"]) {
        SecondUIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.firstView = self;
    }
}
```

When the row is selected in the second view you can use

```
if (self.firstView)    
    [self.firstView setWYPT:[allWYPTs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

to pass the data back to the first view.

---

As said, this would be a quick solution when always the same two classes are involved.

An other way would be to use protocols. When the first view controller won't always be FirstUIVierController, you may use something like this:

**SecondUIViewController.h**

```
@class SecondUIViewController;
@protocol SecondUIViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)secondUIViewController:(SecondUIViewController*)controller didSelectWYPT:(NSMutableDictionary*)wypt;

@end

@interface SecondUIViewController : UIViewController

@property id<SecondUIViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**SecondUIViewController.m**

where the row is selected:

```
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(secondUIViewController:didSelectWYPT:)])
    [self.delegate secondUIViewController:self didSelectWYPT:[allWYPTs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

**AnyOtherUIViewController.h**

```
#import "SecondUIViewController.h"

@interface AnyOtherUIViewController : UIViewController <SecondUIViewControllerDelegate>

...
...
```

**AnyOtherViewController.m**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifier"]) {
        SecondUIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void)secondUIViewController:(SecondUIViewController*)controller didSelectWYPT:(NSMutableDictionary*)wypt {
    //do something with the data
}
```

Comment: Very nicely explained and implemented solution. :)

Comment: thanks for explanation... but the property returns the error: Unknown type name... in the .h file is #import "nameOftheClass.h" implemented...

Comment: @yorh To close the popover, after passing the values back to the first view controller, you could use: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. About the unknown type name, make sure you don't import each other in both .h files! The FirstViewController.h should be imported in the second's **.h** file. The SecondViewController.h should be imported in the first's **.m** file..